# Can buttermilk be frozen successfully?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, buttermilk

Can I freeze unused buttermilk bought at the supermarket for later use? Can it later on be thawed and used safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can freeze buttermilk.

When thawed, the emulsion will break into solids and whey.   This makes no difference for baked goods; you can also use a blender to restore it to a smooth, thicker liquid if needed for applications like salad dressing.

See also:

- [Video from America's Test Kitchen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHXcP7sO3sI).
- [The Kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/good-tip-freezing-leftover-but-58239)